# if, совместно с try - except

Tags: python, python-3.x

Отдельно if работает, отдельно try - except тоже работает. Вместе ну никак не получается у меня их объединить....
В коде ниже, всё работает кроме if ....

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
import paramiko

a1 = 'version3'
a2 = 'version5'

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)
file = open('/etc/openvpn/client.addr', 'r')
for line in file:
    timestamps = str(datetime.now())
    #print('Timestamp:', timestamps)
    info = {}
    info['ip'] = line.split(',')[1]
    info['mac'] = line.split(',')[0]

    def connector():

        ip_log = 'Connecting to IP: ' + info['ip']
        print(ip_log)

        client.connect(info['ip'], username='', port=22, password='', timeout=12)
    stdin1, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('cat /proc/cpuinfo')
        data = stdout.read() + stderr.read()

    try:
        connector()
        if a1 in str(data):
            filename = open('log.txt', 'w')
            filename.write(info['mac'] + ' - version 3')
        if a2 in str(data):
            filename = open('log.txt', 'w')
            filename.write(info['mac'] + ' - version 5')

    except Exception as e:
                error_log = str(e)
                print('error_log')

file.close()
```

Comment: ошибки в студию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело не в `try` или `if`, а в том, что у вас в функции `connector` переменная `data` локальная, поэтому при попытке обратиться к ней извне функции вы получите ошибку, что переменная `data` не определена. Чтобы решить данную проблему, просто возвращайте данные через `return`:

```
def connector():
    # ...
    return stdout.read() + stderr.read()  # возвращаем данные через return

try:
    data = connector()
    if a1 in str(data):
        filename = open('log.txt', 'w')
        filename.write(info['mac'] + ' - version 3')
    if a2 in str(data):
        filename = open('log.txt', 'w')
        filename.write(info['mac'] + ' - version 5')
except Exception as e:  # << не делайте так, ловите всегда конкретные исключения
    error_log = str(e)
    print(error_log)  # << тут была ошибка, всегда выводилась строка "error_log"
```

Кстати, из-за ошибки при обработке исключения вы скорее всего не видели, что за исключение у вас вылетает. Отлавливание общего класса исключений `Exception` плюс вывод строки `"error_log"` вместо содержимого переменной `error_log` дали свой кумулятивный эффект.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало =)